# wp_list_pages(); Change output of hyperlink

Tags: custom-post-types, twitter-bootstrap, wp-list-pages

I am creating a menu for a documentation site very much like this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

I am using a hierarchical custom post type (manual). 
I am currently using wp_list_pages() to output the list. This gives me the nested  structure that I am looking for:

```
<ul>
  <li>Parent Post</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Child Post</li>
      <li>Child Post</li>
    </ul>
  <li>Parent Post</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Child Post</li>
      <li>Child Post</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
<!-- and so on -->
```

Unfortunately, wp_list_pages() outputs the permalink to the post like this:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-332"><a href="http://myurl.com/manual/introduction-to-the-manual/organization/">1.1 &#8211; Manual Organization</a></li>
```

and I need it to output the post_id like this:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-332"><a href="#332">1.1 &#8211; Manual Organization</a></li>
```

Also, here is my wp_list_pages code:

```
 <ul id="markdown-toc">
   <li><h3><a href="#contents">Contents</a></h3></li>
   <ul id="my_cutom_type-list">
     <?php wp_list_pages( 'post_type=manual&title_li=' ); ?>
   </ul>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a filter on `post_type_link`, which allows modification of custom post type permalinks before they are output.

The filter passes the custom post object as the 2nd argument, so we can use that to get the ID and form the new permalink:

```
function wpd_list_pages_permalink_filter( $permalink, $page ){
    return '#' . $page->ID;
}
```

Then you can add and remove the filter when using `wp_list_pages`:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpd_list_pages_permalink_filter', 10, 2 );

wp_list_pages();

remove_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpd_list_pages_permalink_filter', 10, 2 );
```

If your menu contained the built in `page` post type, you would use the `page_link` filter. Note in that case the 2nd argument is only the page's ID, not the full page object like in the `post_type_link` filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can done this by creating you custom Walker class and pass it's instance as argument while calling `wp_list_pages()` function.

The purpose of Walker class is

> It simply traces each branch of your tree: it has to be extended by
>   other classes which tell it what to do for each element it comes
>   across.

Put this class inside your `functions.php` file or `plugins` file.

```
class linkModifyWalker extends Walker_Page {


function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='dropdown-menu children'>\n";
}


function start_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_page = 0 ) {
    if ( $depth )
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    else
        $indent = '';

    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
    $css_class = array('page_item', 'page-item-'.$page->ID);

    if( isset( $args['pages_with_children'][ $page->ID ] ) )
        $css_class[] = 'page_item_has_children dropdown';

    if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
        $_current_page = get_post( $current_page );
        if ( in_array( $page->ID, $_current_page->ancestors ) )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
        if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
        elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
    } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
        $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
    }


    $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );
    $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a href="#' .$page->ID . '">' . $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after . '</a>';


    }
}
```

We have just created `linkModifyWalker` class now,We need to pass it's object to the `wp_list_pages()` as a argument. 
`'walker' => new linkModifyWalker()`

```
<ul id="markdown-toc">
   <li><h3><a href="#contents">Contents</a></h3></li>
   <ul id="my_cutom_type-list">
     <?php 
     wp_list_pages( array(
         'post_type'=> 'manual',
         'walker' => new linkModifyWalker()
     ) ); 
     ?>
   </ul>
 </ul>
```

To know more about what is Walker Class. I recommend you to visit below link.

[Understanding the Walker Class](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-the-walker-class--wp-25401)